# What is this 60's movie about small "mafia"?

Tags: identify-this-movie

Does anyone recognize this movie?

The film is set around 50s/60s in I'm guessing New York. There are a few kids that caught a police officer with two young prostitutes (I believe it was on the roof of some building) so they blackmail him. They would commit small crimes (e.g. steal) and the police officer would overlook those crimes.

That is all I saw from the movie, I would like to see the whole thing but can't find the name anywhere.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is a long time since I saw it, but it sounds a bit like the beginning part of [*Once Upon a Time in America*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087843/). But it's set a bit earlier (20s/30s) and I'm really unsure and should rather recheck the scene you mentioned but this was the first image coming to my mind when reading your question.